# What's shell equivalent for killall if a python script is to be terminated?

Tags: python, shell, unix

So I have a binary file (binApp) to be killed

```
killall -9 binApp
```

Now, instead of using that binary file, I created another python script (pyBinapp.py) to execute the same task. I would like to kill that python task, will this work:

```
killall -9 pyBinApp
```

?

Also, what is that -9 mean? I couldn't find any article regarding this number.

Comment: -9 means kill it without sending kill signal to program and letting it close itself and do its cleanup .... not sure what the rest of your question is asking ...

Comment: I think you just kill the python process, `python.exe`.

Comment: So basically I am to modify the "killall -9 binApp" to something that kills an equivalent python script. When I say equivalent, I mean for example, the binApp and python script both do the calculation of 1+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-9 is the signal to send (instead of the default SIGTERM) - SIGKILL. SIGTERM can be ignored by the application while SIGKILL cannot.

I don't thing it's safe to use killall in that case because you'd have to 'killall python' which may kill other things that are running. 'ps aux | grep python' to see what is running.

EDIT: Actually - I just tested it and so long as you're running pyBinapp.py directly (it's executable and contains #!) instead of passing it as an argument to python (eg python pyBinapp.py) you can kill it with killall pyBinapp.py

Comment: But if I run the pyBinApp.py from shell, I need to pass it as an argument to python... How should I run it directly?

Comment: add a shebang  `#!/bin/usr/python` (something like that anyway) to the top (1st line) of pyBinApp.py

Comment: Does not work if you are using `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang, what is common practice among Python programmers.

Answer (score 3):

`killall` only matches the process name ("python" in your case), so it does not see script name ("pyBinApp.py") as it is one of python process arguments.

However `pgrep` can match against the full argument list with the `-f` flag, including the script file name.

If you're running `python pyBinApp.py`, try this to kill it:

```
kill `pgrep -f pyBinApp.py`
```

`pgrep` returns all PIDs matching the pattern and than `kill` is executed on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
pgrep -f youAppFile.py | xargs kill -9
```

pgrep return the PID of the specific file and you kill only the specific application.

Answer (score 0):

**pkill** does it directly, without the need of grepping it and piping it to kill.

```
pkill -f pyBinApp
```

Does exactly what you want.